# File Upload - Error executing ListObjects | AWS S3 & Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, guzzle

I am getting the error below when i try to upload a file greater than 25mb to amazon s3 using laravel aws sdk, however files below 25mb are uploading successfully. I have everything setup correctly in my **.env** file. I have no idea why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Error:**

> Error executing "ListObjects" on
>   "**bucketdomain**/?prefix=b6d767d2f8ed5d21a44b0e5886680cb9%**filename**%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url";
>   AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to **bucketdomain**
>   port 443: Network unreachable (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

**Save function in laravel:**

```
$v = Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
unlink($file->getPathname());

return response()->json(["message" => "File uploaded successfully!"]);
```

**Upload function in laravel:**

```
if ($receiver->isUploaded() === false) {
      throw new UploadMissingFileException();
}

$save = $receiver->receive();
if ($save->isFinished()) {
      database entries...
      return $this->saveChunkFile($file,$userFolderName,$path,$fileName);
}

$handler = $save->handler();
return response()->json([
     "Percentage" => $handler->getPercentageDone()
]);
```

I am using reusable.js in client side to upload files in chunks & the code above is to handle the chunks and merge them when done and pass to the saveChunkFile function.

Picture:

[image]

The file is to be stored in the 2nd folder from top but there is not file that is why i think the error is thrown on size function and these files (chunks) are being generated and not stopping still.

Comment: Can you share the code with us ?

Comment: Which code? laravel?

Comment: The error you've shared doesn't look related to the issue you're reporting. What code generates that error?

Comment: i don't think the issue is with the code because it works with files up to 23-25 mb as i have noticed but doesn't works for more than that but still i have added the code you can check.

Comment: Do you get "network unreachable" with *all* large files? Or only sometimes?

Comment: Also, which **specific** line throws that error? Laravel should give you a line number.

Comment: all large files ,i think i got it i return some messages after different function calls and i found out that the save function is working properly i returned a response after the saveChunkFile function call and it worked that means error is happening after that and there is only 1 call which is being made to s3 is this : Storage::disk('s3')->size($path) to get the size of the stored file but the problem is that the file is not yet saved at that path because it is still saving and i know that because i just saw that weird files are being stored on the bucket after few secs , added picture check

Comment: how can i wait for the saving to be done (storage->put) and then progress with unlinking and return response

Comment: yes so i tried to return response after the size function which results in the same error hence the problem is rising from the storage->size() function due to no file present in provided path

Comment: now its sometimes saying host unreachable and sometimes network unreachable.

Comment: Network/host unreachable points to issues with your server's connection and isn't likely to be the fault of the code.